# How to make event: when definite tabpage in tabcontrol is chosen - treeview control become disable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, tabcontrol

Something like this:

```
private void secondTabPageInTabControl_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
           this.myTreeView.Enable = false; 
        } //then I chose other tabpages and it becomes enable
```

Comment: How many tabpages are we talking about? Do you want to use one event handler for all? What exactly is your problem/question? You can just create an event handler for all tabs and just enable or disable the treeview like your are doing now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the TabControl's SelectedIndexChanged event instead.  It tells you when a new tab is selected.  Use code similar to this:

```
    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.myTreeView.Enable = tabControl1.SelectedTab != tabPage2;
    }
```

Or by index, less readable:

```
    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.myTreeView.Enable = tabControl1.SelectedIndex != 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution, but note that this could become bloated if you use too many tabpages:

```
    private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateUI(e.TabPageIndex);    
    }

    public void UpdateUI(int index)
    {
        switch (index)
        { 
            case 0:
                treeView1.Enabled = true;
                break;
            case 1:
                treeView1.Enabled = false;
                break;
            case 2:
                treeView1.Enabled = false;
                break;
            default:
                treeView1.Enabled = false;
                break;
        }
    }
```